# Any good alternative to using SVGAnimationElement.beginElement()?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I've just discovered that `SVGAnimationElement.beginElement()` is classified as ["an experimental API that should not be used in production code"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement). I'm currently depending on using `beginElement()` to create a mechanical animation effect for the second hand of an analog-style clock (which can be seen here: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/OZpvKj/).

Here are the most relevant parts of the code:

```
<line id="sec-hand" x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="12">
  <animateTransform id="sweep"
                    attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate"
                    from="270 50 50" to="276 50 50" dur="0.2s"
                    values="270 50 50; 278 50 50; 276 50 50"
                    calcMode="spline"
                    keyTimes="0; 0.75; 1" keySplines="0.5 0 1 0.5; 0 0.5 0.5 1"
                    repeatCount="1">
</line>
```

...

```
function sweepSecondHand(start, end) {
  if (end < start) {
    end += 360;
  }

  sweep.setAttribute('from', start + ' 50 50');
  sweep.setAttribute('to', end + ' 50 50');
  sweep.setAttribute('values', start + ' 50 50; ' + (end + 2) + ' 50 50; ' + end + ' 50 50')
  sweep.beginElement();
}
```

In the SVG I've filled in the attributes necessary to describe moving the second hand from the top of the minute to one second after. But I need to periodically replace the values of those attributes with the specific values needed to display the current time.

Merely replacing the values isn't enough to move the second hand as desired. I seem to need `beginElement()` to restart the animation using the new values. I've been happy with the result, but now that I know `beginElement()` is non-standard, I'd rather not rely on it.

Can anyone suggest a standards-friendly alternative that yields the same results?

UPDATE:

I experimented with removing the `animateTransform` element and building/appending a new one for each tick of the second hand -- that achieved nothing until I called `beginElement()` on the newly created `animateTransform` element.

Comment: You've misread the page. It's the onbegin event that it says might change, though I've no idea why it says that. It might well be wrong there. Personally I don't think you need to do anything.

Comment: What I saw is down further on that same page in the Methods section -- just like the `onbegin` event handler, `beginElement()` is marked with a blue flask icon. Mouse over that icon, and you'll see the warning.

Comment: I see no beginElement() with a blue flask icon, just onbegin.

Comment: Anyway its all wrong, onbegin is not experimental either.

Comment: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/1956